# React Native navigator, prevent static navigationOptions component being unmounted when back after push()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

App root:

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    initialRouteParams: {text: 'example'},
  },
);
```

---

`Constructor()` from HomeScreen:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: this.props.navigation.state.params.url,
    };
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      toggleMenu: this.toggleMenu.bind(this),
    });
  }
```

---

`Render()` from HomeScreen:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Home', {text: 'another example'})}>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    const toggleMenu = navigation.getParam('toggleMenu', () => null);
    return {
      headerTitle: () => (
        <AddressBar
          navigation={navigation}
          toggleMenu={toggleMenu}
        />
      ),
    };
  };
```

---

I'm using `push()` to duplicate the `HomeScreen` with a different param and everything works fine. The problem is when I'm going back to the initial screen, `<AddressBar />` from `static navigationOptions` is unmounted. I need to keep it mounted because I'm passing a `HomeScreen` method as a prop to the `<AddressBar />`. After invoking the `push()` everything works fine, I can use `HomeScreen` method from the `<AddressBar />` component. The problem is that when I'm going back, the `<AddressBar />` component is unmounted.

Is there any way to prevent unmounting `<AddressBar />` component? I've tried to use listener `'willFocus'` on the `<AddressBar />` to set `shouldComponentUpdate()` to `false` on `'willFocus'` but it's not working.

Or can I somehow mount the `<AddressBar />` again?